# Setting various environments (development, production) based on the URL

Tags: php, drupal, development-environment, drupal-7, conventions

I am trying to setup environments in Drupal based on the URL.
For example, if I go to mysite.local, it will use localdb and it will change the name of the site to "Local Mysite"; if I go to mysite.com, it will switch automatically to use productiondb and set the name to "Mysite".

This is a similar setup I use for most MVC based frameworks:

```
define('DEVELOPMENT', 'mysite.local');
define('PRODUCTION', 'mysite.com');

switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
  case DEVELOPMENT:
    // development server
    $config['base_url']    = "http://mysite.local";
    $config['title']    = "DEVELOPMENT Mysite";
    $config['debug']    = 1;
    break;

  default:
    // live server
    $config['base_url']    = "http://mysite.com/";
    $config['title']    = "Mysite";
    $config['debug']    = 0;
    break;
}
```

Is there something like that in Drupal7 already (I don't want to use different sites, only different settings for the same site), and is there some sort of convention where this switch needs to happen (I am currently thinking about settings.php).

Comment: I suggest you have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9/suggestions-for-settings-php-local-dev-development-server-live-server/41#41, especially my answer there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I don't commit settings.php into version control, (settings.default.php is), then just keep a custom settings.php file based off settings.default.php in each environment.

However, if you prefer to setup your environments that way, then something like this would work in your sites/default/settings.php file.

```
define('DEVELOPMENT', 'mysite.local');
define('PRODUCTION', 'mysite.com');

switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
  case DEVELOPMENT:
    // development server
    $db_url = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/mydb_dev';
    $db_prefix = '';
    $base_url = 'http://mysite.local';
    $conf = array(
     'site_name' => 'Development Environment',
    );
    break;

  default:
    // live server
    $db_url = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/mydb_prod';
    $db_prefix = '';
    $base_url = 'http://mysite.com';
    $conf = array(
     'site_name' => 'My Site',
    );
    break;
}
```

Remember, for each of these vars you use here, you need to comment out if they are defined in other parts of settings.php.

I should also add that I think multi-site for the purpose of a development environment is a bad idea, I guess for the same reason I prefer each environment having it's own custom settings.php file. In most cases, I prefer to keep the code portable in that I do not need any code or file system references to any environment except in a settings file for the environment I'm running the code on.

Using Drupal's multi-site functionality for every environment you need to develop and stage on, as others are suggesting here, would be insane to manage.

Comment: Probably this is the way I will go. I need it that way, so I can deploy directly from my SVN, instead of changing files and making sure everything works every time. The matter gets even more complicated when I add staging server to the environment.

Comment: It seems more complicated than it needs to be, but I know each situation is different. If you use the method of just copying settings.default.php to settings.php (i.e. settings.php not being in version control) in each environment one time, then you should be able to deploy via svn just fine since your settings files will never be touched. Configuring each settings.php file once to me is easier and more portable than managing all that data in a single settings.php file.

Comment: Note that Drush seems to be using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and not $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called [multi-site configuration](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/advanced-multisite), in Drupal.
Said with few words, in a multi-site configuration, you are setting Drupal to use different configuration files basing on the domain name used to access the site. It allows to use the same code for different domain names that point all to the same server, as in your case, where you want to access the same web server using different domain names.

You are also interested in what reported in [Run multiple sites from the same code base (multi-site)](http://drupal.org/getting-started/6/install/multi-site).

Comment: Thank you.
I am aware of the "multi-site" feature of Drupal, but that means having different folders, modules, uploads, etc per every environment. I used this before, but I want something different. I want to be able to set different environments for the same site (the folder for the site is always "default", but the name, database and some other settings will be set based on the URL). In other words, I deploy it on my local box, the DB will be switched automatically to my local DB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using separate sites is what you want.  I have a similar setup, and the different sites each have their own settings.php file.  But then I symlinked the modules and themes directory so that I don't have duplicate files.  But if you are setting up one environment for development, you will want to keep them separate.

So I have something like this:

```
drupal/sites/mysite.com/themes
drupal/sites/mysite.com/modules
drupal/sites/mysite.com/settings.php

drupal/sites/mysite.local/themes => ../../mysite.com/themes
drupal/sites/mysite.local/modules => ../../mysite.com/modules
drupal/sites/mysite.local/settings.php

drupal/sites/default => mysite.com
```

Drupal will use the correct site configuration based on the URL.

Comment: This is something similar to what I want, but I thought that there should be a better way in Drupal to set those up, since I can't use symlink (Windows Dev machine), and those links will get messed up when moving to a different machine. I guess that the short answer will be that there is nothing in place like this, and either I have to go with the "multi-site" and have repeating files, modules, etc which will lead to fragmentation, or to edit the settings.php and set it up like I have it above...